# Simple question about array with 'int[int] for array subscript' error

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm a beginner in C++. I try do array with recursion but kept getting error: *"invalid types 'int[int] for array subscript"*. How do I solve this?

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int array_sum(int a[], int b[])
{
    if(a<=0)
        return 0;
    else
        return (array_sum(a, b-1) + a[b-1]);
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {4, 2, 2};
    int b[] = {4, 3, 2, 8};

    cout << array_sum(a, 3) << endl;
    cout << array_sum(b, 4) << endl;
}
```

p/s: any suggestion for improvement is appreciated

Comment: This looks wrong: `int b[]`, and also `a <= 0`.

Comment: You are trying to pass 3 and 4 to int b[].

Comment: You have to think about the code you write. It seems like you are making guesses. In `int array_sum(int a[], int b[])` If a is an array `a <= 0` makes no sense or at least c++ does not work like that.  And if b is an array `return (array_sum(a, b-1) + a[b-1]);` makes no sense. In this case `b` should probably be named better  and be just an `int`. And then in main for the second parameter declared as an array you pass 3 and 4 instead of an array.

Answer (score 1):

Given the types involved in the following are:

```
int a[], int b[]
```

Then the expression `a[b-1]` is indexing an array with another array, which doesn't make any sense and directly matches the error you're given.